# Details in facade gone when render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

Something strange has happend to my model of a balcony on a facade. I have rendered this several times without problems, but yesterday I just made some minor changes. Since then when I do a final rendering with <kbd>F12</kbd> key the facade just gets white with no details. However, when I do a prerender with <kbd>Shift + Z</kbd>, the image looks just as the 3D model. Despite that I have 3000 samples, the facade is just white. I’m using Blender 2.79b and Cycles.

Any clue what has happend and how I can fix it?!

The prerender:

[image]

The real render:

[image]

Comment: if you try to render something else does it work? could you share this part of your object?

Comment: @moonboots Hi! Thanks for your answer! I think I have solved it. I moved the facade 1mm towards the camera. I don't know why this worked since the clipping settings for the camera was correct.